# How do I change the default directory that pip installs to?

Tags: python, pip

When I run the commmand

```
pip install virtualenv
```

I get:

```
Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/share/python
```

But my default `virtualenv` is in a different place:

```
which virtualenv
usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

I'd like `pip` to install to the `usr/local/bin` directory by default. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to manually decide where you want packages to reside, you could always download the source distribution to a directory of your choice with the following:

```
pip install -d <path_to_my_directory>
```

But when you install, I think you probably want to put the executable console scripts (as defined in the package's setup.py file; like virtualenv for example) in a directory included in your $PATH environmental variable.

You can specify this manually by doing the following:

```
sudo python setup.py install --install-scripts /usr/bin/
```

or`sudo python setup.py install --install-scripts /usr/local/bin/`

Let me know if you have any other questions...

Comment: I was able to make this edit, but I'm afraid I went over my head with this. Now when when I try to run virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper I get other errors 'File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 518, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.8.2'

Comment: thank you for your help, I ended up having to add usr/local/share to my paths because pip was putting everything in there. Big mess but looks like i patched it together

Comment: glad you got it working. Once you have the virtualenv activated, console scripts will be put in a virtualenv-specific bin directory.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider upgrading to Python 2.6

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/local/bin` is for executable programs.  `/usr/local/share` is to store data that is independent of the architecture.

So, in your case, you are installing by default in `/usr/local`, where the executable programs live in /usr/local/bin, the arquitecture-independent data lives in `/usr/local/share`, configuration files live in `/usr/local/etc`, etc.

You can check [Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to get an overview on the topic.