# Pip install python package into a specific directory other than the default install location

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, pip, enthought

The default location where pip installes packages on my Ubuntu system is '/usr/local/lib/pytho2.7/dist-packages/' which I think is the default in general. I am using Enthought python distribution (EPD not canopy) and would like to install a package into EPD as I usually work with the python from the EPD distribution on my system. I would like to know into which directory  inside EPD the new files need to be installed using pip ; as the directory structure for EPD on linux seems to be quite different from the EPD directory structure on MAC OS for where there seem to be many examples.

Also I have come across this :

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

as the accepted answer to a question similar to this. I would like to know what the purpose of the $PREFIX_PATH environment variable is as mine is currently blank. And what path I need to specify on Ubuntu for my Enthought EPD distribution to install python modules.

I apologize for the relatively naive question but I am quite new to EPD on ubuntu and am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: have you considered using virtualenv ?

Comment: yes but I would like to know how to do this without using a virtualenv.

Comment: this might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/pip-how-do-i-install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory

Comment: You're ment to replace `$PREFIX_PATH` with whatever install directory you'd like to have.

Answer (score 51):

This line should work for everyone, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-t).

```
pip install package_name -t any/path/i/like
```

PS:

And to address the comment of @CPiLL, the `any/path/i/like` can really be anything, such as `/tmp/my-test-env`. The package being installed in this way will **NOT** be available for your usual python environment, in fact they will NOT even show up using `pip list`. And `python -c "import package_name"` will generally FAIL with ImportError exception, unless you cd into that folder first:

```
cd /tmp/my-test-env
python -c "import package-name"
```

How this technique would be useful is beyond this answer.

Comment: `error: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both`

Comment: I think `pip install X --user` is the shortcut

Comment: Readable command: `pip install --target any/path/i/like package_name`

Answer (score 5):

System: Ubuntu 12.04, Enthought Python Distribution (this is where I wanted to install a new python module)

So the prefix_path environment variable didn't work for me and pip still kept installing it in the default location. But I used 
   [How do I change the default directory that pip installs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595778/change-default-directory-for-pip-install)

question as a guide. And one of the answers helped me achieve what I needed.

```
 pip install -d <path_to_my_directory>
```

For the path I used: 
    path_to_epd_directory/lib/python2.7/site-packages

This puts the tar.gz file into the site-packages

Then extract it using:

tar -zxvf pymodule.tar.gz

a directory named pymodule is created, cd into that module and type:

```
 python setup.py install
```

and that should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you could use a copy of `pip` that has been installed into your EPD installation.

```
$ path-to-EPD/bin/enpkg pip # Or simply enpkg pip, if EPD is on your PATH. 
$ path-to-EPD/bin/pip install <package-name>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.
Installing PyMySQL to specific dir:

```
sudo pip install PyMySQL -t /home/mahmoud/app
```

Comment: `sudo pip install` should never be used.

Answer (score -1):

*This answer worked in windows OS*
**Short answer:** To install package to the specific folder using `-t` option ex:`pip install packageX -t lib/`, then add this folder to `PYTHONPAHT`

**Long answer:**

1. install virtualenv to `.env` folder
2. pip install with -t option, example install to lib folder of my project (named `3`)
   `(.env) d:\tmp\3>pip install packageX -t lib/`
3. show list of packages :

```
    (.env) d:\tmp\3>pip list
    Package    Version
    ---------- ----------
    pip        18.1
    setuptools 40.6.3
    ...
```

3. Not see your package ? open command-prompt as administrator right and set PYTHONPATH

[image]

4. now new command prompt and activate env will see your packages 
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to install you package to a specific path.

```
pip install [package name] --target /path/to
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment to what your code does. A single code line without any feedback is a very low quality answer

Comment: This is the same as the top answer from years ago.  `-t` is just shorthand for `--target`.