# How to change pip unpacking folder?

Tags: python, linux, pip, space

I need to install tensorflow on my Raspberry, but executing `pip install tensorflow` (or any other `pip install`) ends up with a Errno 28 "No space left on device".

I tried solution 2 of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1288308/why-am-i-getting-no-space-left-on-device-when-it-appears-that-theres-lots-of) with no effect, [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816) but it says it's deprecated, and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216689/pip-install-python-package-into-a-specific-directory-other-than-the-default-inst).

I understand the problem lies in the fact that I don't have enough space in the directory where the unpacking occurs (the first one below) because when I use `df` it produces this (sorry headers are in french) :

[image]

I even tried to `export TMPDIR=PATH_TO_A_BIGGER_ONE` but it still can't complete the download because of no space.

I just can't find a way to change this directory.

Answer (score 14):

Both **TMPDIR** and **Target directory** should be big enough.

```
TMPDIR=PATH_TO_A_BIGGER_ONE pip install [package name] --target ANOTHER_PATH_TO_A_BIGGER_ONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following [this guide](https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/use-tensorflow-in-aws-lambda-free-tier#creating-an-efs-file-system) and ran into the same problem you describe. These steps solved it for me:

1. Create a temp folder on a disk that has a lot of space:

   `mkdir -p /bigtempfolder`
2. Change TMPDIR env to the big folder you just created:

   `export TMPDIR=/bigtempfolder`
3. Set generous access to the temp folder:

   `sudo chmod 777 /bigtempfolder`
4. (Create a Swap file if you have limited RAM on the machine):

   1. Create a Swap of 4 GB:

      `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096`
   2. Format the file for Swap usage:

      `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
   3. Activate Swap file:

      `sudo swapon /swapfile`
   4. Make the Swap permanent:

      `echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`
   5. Verify that the swap is now activated:

      `sudo swapon --show`
5. Install the package(s) using the `--cache-dir` flag:

   `pip --cache-dir /bigtempfolder install tensorflow`