# Pip and Virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, pip, virtualenv

I have been following instructions that I found online to try to use `virtualenv`

My steps were:

1. `sudo easy_install pip`  - I'm doing this in my home directory
2. `sudo pip install virtualenv` - I think virtualenv is installed at this point because
                                 when I try again, it says Requirement already satisfied
3. The instructions then tell me to cd to my desktop and type in `virtualenv env`
   yet the output is as follows `"-bash: virtualenv: command not found"`

Does it mean that the shell can't find the command `virtualenv`? I thought I installed it.

Comment: Yes, it means the shell can't find the command.  Try opening a new shell.

Comment: Also make sure that where the binaries lie, those folder(s) are in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PATH` should contains directory where virtualenv installed. your `pip` might install into `/usr/local/bin` (or other pip's default directory).

you can add some pathes in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile~` files.

```
$ cat ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

if you can't find `virtualenv` in `/usr/local/bin`, then you might want to change pip install directory with `-d` option.

```
$ pip install -d your_path virtualenv
...
$ your_path/virtualenv
```

if `PATH` include `your_path`, simply use

```
$ virtualenv
```

And [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595778/how-do-i-change-the-default-directory-that-pip-installs-to) can help you.